# Django is not responding urls.py file

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am writing basic views and then putting it in urls.py but it is still not working.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello how are you")
```

project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('',include('blog.urls')),
     ]
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
        path('home/',views.home,name='home')
    ]
```

I have also included my app in settings of project (Installed apps).

Comment: if your app in project directory try to add project name: path('',include('PROJECT.blog.urls')),

Comment: Still it is not responding

Comment: Actually if i add direct url in projects urls.py like (from myapp import views) still it does not show anything and show that there is only admin url

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts about that:

Change your urls patterns in your apps urls to:

```
from .views import *
urlpatterns= [
    path('', home,name='home')
]
```

If its not working send us your installed apps settings and wsgi file

Answer (score 0):

You confused, you need to write `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home` not only `http://127.0.0.1:8000` with your current code.

If you want the view to be rendered in default route so change urls.py as:

```py
from . import views

urlpatterns= [
    path('', views.home,name='home')
]
```

Otherwise, you can only append `/home` with your current code to work.

Comment: I tried it ,but it is not working

Comment: @shafquet So the problem is you are not able to see the page which says `hello how are you`? Does it show some error or blank page? Tell me more about that.

Comment: When i keep blank inside the path in urls.py :8000  shows django successful page and when i use path ("home/",views.home) and :8000/home/ shows error page home does not exist and shows only admin is available

Comment: @shafquet can you share the full error traceback?

Comment: @shafquet Did the problem solve?

Comment: yes,acually i was not saving my file before reloading .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for the same code above it is working for the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/